# How to set blink on CCSprite image?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I want to set *blink* on my `CCSprite` in Cocos2D.

How to set blink in `Cocos2d` ??

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
CCSprite * m_Sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"sprite.png"];

[m_Sprite runAction:[CCBlink actionWithDuration:1 blinks:5]];
```